# @grant directive and detecting a user script by a page

Tags: tampermonkey, userscripts

My question is two-fold. First, can someone explain what are pros and cons of using `@grant none` in Tampermonkey? And second, which `@grant` values I should use to prevent a webpage from detecting a script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [@grant](https://www.tampermonkey.net/documentation.php#_grant)
>
> If @grant is followed by 'none' the sandbox is disabled and the script
> will run directly at the page context. In this mode no GM_* function
> but the GM_info property will be available.

If a script doesn't need any `@grant` i.e. the script is plain JavaScript without any GM API, you can use `@grant none`. Tampermonkey then injects the script into `page` context (same context as the JavaScript of the webpage).

Normally userscripts are injected into `content` context which is separated from the `page` context.

If the userscript is injected into `page` context, then it would be easier for the page to find it. Similarly, if a userscript injected into `content` context but uses `unsafeWindow` to interact with the webpage script.

Webpages can not automatically detect userscripts, but they can check for the result of a script.

For example ...

- webpage adds an ad
- userscript removes the ad
- webpage check if the ad is still there or not

Webpage may also look for specific globals that a userscript might add (if the userscript adds globals to the `page` context).

Comment: So it seems that an average "privacy-concerned" user would prefer to **not** use `@grant none`, even if the userscript is plain JS without any GM API, and this decision will be because using `@grant none` makes it easier to detect the userscript, right? But then, what is the reason to use `@grant none` at all?

Comment: @johnc.j. Please note that the behavior of userscript managers are not unified so above will only apply to TM. For example in VM missing `@grant` is the same as `@grant none`. Detecting the existence of the userscript mostly depends on how the userscript is coded and not as much on `@grant`. The example with the ad that I gave, doesn't depend on `@grant` or the context.

Comment: I think it would be fair to accept and award your answer, but if you could explain the second part of the previous comment, it would be great :) If `@grant none` often means make it easier to detect a script, what is the purpose to use it at all? What are some basic cases in which you will need it nevertheless?

Comment: @johnc.j. `@grant none` shows that the script doesn't use any GM API which could mean it is safer. GM APIs run in the different scope and have more power than the standard JavaScript. The behavior of injecting `@grant none` scripts into `page` context, is a decision made by TM. For example, a script that sets a global variable, can be detected if the webpage looks for that particular variable (must know it in advance) and it doesn't matter if there is a `@grant` or not. `@grant` is more related to the user than the webpage. Generally speaking, most userscripts wont be detected by the webpage.