# Is there a way to get userscript code that was evaluated on the page?

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey, userscripts

I have created userscripts to ease logging in my accounts on some websites, but now I'm concerned:
Can a site owner see the code of my userscripts?

I'm using Tampermonkey extension for Edge/Chrome, and "Userscripts" Extension/App for iOS Safari.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, websites don't & can't detect userscripts. It all depends on how the userscript code is written and if the website is aware of the such userscript to look for it.

You can read the reply in [@grant directive and detecting a user script by a page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72375292/grant-directive-and-detecting-a-user-script-by-a-page) which should explain it further.

Comment: As I understand from that question, there is no way for site owner to view userscript's source code. Am I right?

Comment: @Alex That is generally true but a specifically written userscript can become partially visible to the webpage if webpage is looking for it. Imagine a userscript injects a `<script>` element into the page and that has some functions/variables. If the site is checking for any elements added to the page then it can find that `<script>` element; or a userscript that sets a global `xyz` variable and if site checks for that global `xyz` then it would also have access to it. It mostly comes to how the userscript is written and how it is exposed to the webpage JavaScript.